# IE11 - Unhandled Promise rejection: Syntax error

Tags: angular, typescript, internet-explorer-11, es6-promise

I am working on an Angular 2 application and for the first time added some `async/await` features. Everything works fine locally but once its deployed on my test server where I receive this error in `IE11` (*see bottom of question for complete browser stack trace*):

> Unhandled Promise rejection: Syntax error

**The error occurs when the Angular2 application is being loaded**, not when the method executes. The error points to this method (*it also happens to be the only method in this component*).

**my-component.ts**

```
async logoff(event: { preventDefault: () => void }) {
    event.preventDefault();
    await this.authService.logoff();
    window.location.href = '/Account/Login';
}
```

It is the first time I have introduced `async/await` so I know this is the point of the failure.

### Testing Steps

- I use Visual Studio to publish a release version to my local IIS. Spces are:

  - Windows 10 (x64)
  - IIS
- I then run install my npm packages I need for production environment in my published directory

  ```
  npm i --production
  ```
- I open the `IE11` browser and run the application from IIS and **everything works, no errors**.
- I then make a complete copy of my published directory and copy it to my test server. Test server spces are:

  - Windows 2012 R2 Standard
  - IIS
- I then browser to the site using the same IE11 browser instance on my Dev machine I used previously and receive the error above.

**So why does it fail when I run it from my test server and not fail when I run it from my local machine?** Is there a required Node or NPM module/package that needs to be installed globally for shims to work correctly from IE11 or is there a problem with something else? I am at a loss here.

### Configuration

*If there is anything I can add to this please let me know, I will update the question.*

**tsconfig.js**

*As per [recommended configuration](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/typescript-configuration.html)*

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "lib": [ "es2015", "dom" ],
    "removeComments": false,
    "noImplicitAny": false,
    "suppressImplicitAnyIndexErrors": true
  },
  "compileOnSave": true
}
```

**package.json**

```
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/common": "2.4.8",
    "@angular/compiler": "2.4.8",
    "@angular/core": "2.4.8",
    "@angular/forms": "2.4.8",
    "@angular/http": "2.4.8",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "2.4.8",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "2.4.8",
    "@angular/router": "3.4.8",
    "core-js": "~2.4.1",
    "jquery": "~3.1.1",
    "lodash": "^4.17.4",
    "reflect-metadata": "^0.1.9",
    "rxjs": "5.2.0",
    "systemjs": "0.20.9",
    "zone.js": "^0.7.7"
  }
```

**Index.html** (*scripts only*)

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/core-js/2.4.1/shim.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/rxjs/5.0.1/Rx.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/zone.js/0.7.7/zone.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/reflect-metadata/0.1.8/Reflect.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/systemjs/0.20.9/system.js"></script>
<script>
    System.import('system-config.js')
        .then(function() {
            System.import('main');
        })
        .catch(console.error.bind(console));
</script>
```

**Complete client side stack trace**

```
Unhandled Promise rejection: Syntax error
  Evaluating http://mytest.server.domain/Scripts/my-component.js
  Evaluating http://mytest.server.domain/Scripts/app.module.js
  Evaluating http://mytest.server.domain/Scripts/main.js
  Loading main ; Zone: <root> ; Task: Promise.then ; Value: Error: Syntax error
  Evaluating http://mytest.server.domain/Scripts/my-component.js
  Evaluating http://mytest.server.domain/Scripts/app.module.js
  Evaluating http://mytest.server.domain/Scripts/main.js
  Loading main SyntaxError: Syntax error
   at Pe (https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/systemjs/0.20.9/system.js:4:25003)
   at Anonymous function (https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/systemjs/0.20.9/system.js:5:224)
   at j (https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/systemjs/0.20.9/system.js:4:7593)
   at S (https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/systemjs/0.20.9/system.js:4:7059)
   at x (https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/a
   "Unhandled Promise rejection:"
   "Syntax error
  Evaluating http://mytest.server.domain/Scripts/my-component.js
  Evaluating http://mytest.server.domain/Scripts/app.module.js
  Evaluating http://mytest.server.domain/Scripts/main.js
  Loading main"
   "; Zone:"
   "<root>"
   "; Task:"
   "Promise.then"
   "; Value:"
   {
      [functions]: ,
      __proto__: { },
      __zone_symbol__error: { },
      __zone_symbol__message: "Syntax error
  Evaluating http://mytest.server.domain/Scripts/my-component.js
  Evaluating http://mytest.server.domain/Scripts/app.module.js
  Evaluating http://mytest.server.domain/Scripts/main.js
  Loading main",
      __zone_symbol__number: undefined,
      description: "Syntax error
  Evaluating http://mytest.server.domain/Scripts/my-component.js
  Evaluating http://mytest.server.domain/Scripts/app.module.js
  Evaluating http://mytest.server.domain/Scripts/main.js
  Loading main",
      message: "Syntax error
  Evaluating http://mytest.server.domain/Scripts/my-component.js
  Evaluating http://mytest.server.domain/Scripts/app.module.js
  Evaluating http://mytest.server.domain/Scripts/main.js
  Loading main",
      name: "Error",
      number: undefined,
      originalErr: { },
      originalStack: undefined,
      stack: "SyntaxError: Syntax error
   at Pe (https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/systemjs/0.20.9/system.js:4:25003)
   at Anonymous function (https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/systemjs/0.20.9/system.js:5:224)
   at j (https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/systemjs/0.20.9/system.js:4:7593)
   at S (https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/systemjs/0.20.9/system.js:4:7059)
   at x (https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/systemjs/0.20.9/system.js:4:6096)
   at Anonymous function (https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/systemjs/0.20.9/system.js:4:6268)
   at Anonymous function (eval code:20:1)
   at Anonymous function (eval code:1:31)
   at eval code (eval code:1:2)
   at Pe (https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/systemjs/0.20.9/system.js:4:25003)
   at Anonymous function (https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/systemjs/0.20.9/system.js:5:224)
   at j (https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/systemjs/0.20.9/system.js:4:7593)
   at S (https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/systemjs/0.20.9/system.js:4:7059)
   at x (",
      Symbol()_n.tcfyoms51l2: undefined,
      Symbol()_o.tcfyoms51l2: undefined,
      Symbol()_p.tcfyoms51l2: undefined,
      Symbol()_q.tcfyoms51l2: undefined,
      Symbol()_r.tcfyoms51l2: undefined,
      Symbol()_s.tcfyoms51l2: undefined,
      Symbol()_t.tcfyoms51l2: undefined,
      Symbol()_u.tcfyoms51l2: undefined,
      Symbol(rxSubscriber)_m.tcfyoms51l2: undefined,
      zoneAwareStack: undefined
   }
   "SyntaxError: Syntax error
   at Pe (https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/systemjs/0.20.9/system.js:4:25003)
   at Anonymous function (https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/systemjs/0.20.9/system.js:5:224)
   at j (https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/systemjs/0.20.9/system.js:4:7593)
   at S (https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/systemjs/0.20.9/system.js:4:7059)
   at x (https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/systemjs/0.20.9/system.js:4:6096)
   at Anonymous function (https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/systemjs/0.20.9/system.js:4:6268)
   at Anonymous function (eval code:20:1)
   at Anonymous function (eval code:1:31)
   at eval code (eval code:1:2)
   at Pe (https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/systemjs/0.20.9/system.js:4:25003)
   at Anonymous function (https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/systemjs/0.20.9/system.js:5:224)
   at j (https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/systemjs/0.20.9/system.js:4:7593)
   at S (https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/systemjs/0.20.9/system.js:4:7059)
   at x ("

Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Syntax error
  Evaluating http://mytest.server.domain/Scripts/my-component.js
  Evaluating http://mytest.server.domain/Scripts/app.module.js
  Evaluating http://mytest.server.domain/Scripts/main.js
  Loading main
SyntaxError: Syntax error
   at Pe (https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/systemjs/0.20.9/system.js:4:25003)
   at Anonymous function (https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/systemjs/0.20.9/system.js:5:224)
   at j (https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/systemjs/0.20.9/system.js:4:7593)
   at S (https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/systemjs/0.20.9/system.js:4:7059)
   at x (https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/systemjs/0.20.9/system.js:4:6096)
   at Anonymous function (https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/systemjs/0.20.9/system.js:4:6268)
   at Anonymous function (eval code:20:1)
   at Anonymous function (eval code:1:31)
   at eval code (eval code:1:2)
   at Pe (https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/sys
   {
      [functions]: ,
      __proto__: { },
      __zone_symbol__error: { },
      __zone_symbol__number: undefined,
      description: "Uncaught (in promise): Error: Syntax error
  Evaluating http://mytest.server.domain/Scripts/my-component.js
  Evaluating http://mytest.server.domain/Scripts/app.module.js
  Evaluating http://mytest.server.domain/Scripts/main.js
  Loading main
SyntaxError: Syntax error
   at Pe (https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/systemjs/0.20.9/system.js:4:25003)
   at Anonymous function (https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/systemjs/0.20.9/system.js:5:224)
   at j (https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/systemjs/0.20.9/system.js:4:7593)
   at S (https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/systemjs/0.20.9/system.js:4:7059)
   at x (https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/systemjs/0.20.9/system.js:4:6096)
   at Anonymous function (https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/systemjs/0.20.9/system.js:4:6268)
   at Anonymous function (eval code:20:1)
   at Anonymous function (eval code:1:31)
   at eval code (eval code:1:2)
   at Pe (https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/systemjs/0",
      message: "Uncaught (in promise): Error: Syntax error
  Evaluating http://mytest.server.domain/Scripts/my-component.js
  Evaluating http://mytest.server.domain/Scripts/app.module.js
  Evaluating http://mytest.server.domain/Scripts/main.js
  Loading main
SyntaxError: Syntax error
   at Pe (https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/systemjs/0.20.9/system.js:4:25003)
   at Anonymous function (https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/systemjs/0.20.9/system.js:5:224)
   at j (https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/systemjs/0.20.9/system.js:4:7593)
   at S (https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/systemjs/0.20.9/system.js:4:7059)
   at x (https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/systemjs/0.20.9/system.js:4:6096)
   at Anonymous function (https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/systemjs/0.20.9/system.js:4:6268)
   at Anonymous function (eval code:20:1)
   at Anonymous function (eval code:1:31)
   at eval code (eval code:1:2)
   at Pe (https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/systemjs/0",
      name: "Error",
      number: undefined,
      originalStack: undefined,
      promise: { },
      rejection: { },
      stack: "Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Syntax error
  Evaluating http://mytest.server.domain/Scripts/my-component.js
  Evaluating http://mytest.server.domain/Scripts/app.module.js
  Evaluating http://mytest.server.domain/Scripts/main.js
  Loading main
SyntaxError: Syntax error
   at Pe (https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/systemjs/0.20.9/system.js:4:25003)
   at Anonymous function (https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/systemjs/0.20.9/system.js:5:224)
   at j (https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/systemjs/0.20.9/system.js:4:7593)
   at S (https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/systemjs/0.20.9/system.js:4:7059)
   at x (https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/systemjs/0.20.9/system.js:4:6096)
   at Anonymous function (https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/systemjs/0.20.9/system.js:4:6268)
   at Anonymous function (eval code:20:1)
   at Anonymous function (eval code:1:31)
   at eval code (eval code:1:2)
   at Pe (https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/sys",
      Symbol()_n.tcfyoms51l2: undefined,
      Symbol()_o.tcfyoms51l2: undefined,
      Symbol()_p.tcfyoms51l2: undefined,
      Symbol()_q.tcfyoms51l2: undefined,
      Symbol()_r.tcfyoms51l2: undefined,
      Symbol()_s.tcfyoms51l2: undefined,
      Symbol()_t.tcfyoms51l2: undefined,
      Symbol()_u.tcfyoms51l2: undefined,
      Symbol(rxSubscriber)_m.tcfyoms51l2: undefined,
      task: { },
      zone: { },
      zoneAwareStack: undefined
   }
```

Comment: What if you surround  `await this.authService.logoff();` with a `try/catch` and log the potential error? Do you see an error on your test server ?

Comment: @BrunoGrieder - Thanks for the idea. I just tried it, unfortunately the result is the same.

Comment: I find js engines to become picky when facing 'unhandled rejections' I had to rework quite a bit of code to catch these. On NodeJS, a good way to catch them is to had an handler which will log the line: `process.on('unhandledRejection', (r: Error) => console.log('BUG: Unhandled Rejection', r));`

Comment: How do you call `logoff(event)` ? Do you `.catch()` on it or `await` with a try/catch ?

Comment: @BrunoGrieder - I added clarification, the error occurs when the application is being loaded and not when the method is called (*it does not get that far*).

Comment: Is your CDN sending the expected code, not an old cached version ? The response headers will let you know if this is fresh code or from a cache hit

Comment: @BrunoGrieder - I hate `IE` (*I wanted to write some expletives but am too respectful of SO to do so*). Yes, IE was caching even though I was in development mode (console open) AND was using CTRL+F5. I took your idea and went to the Options menu and used settings to clear everything from the cache. It now works....

Comment: @BrunoGrieder - Thank you very much, you saved my day!

Comment: Makes my day too :)

Comment: @BrunoGrieder - Feel free to submit an answer, I will mark it if you do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the various caches that come into play: IE and your CDN; you may be loading an old cached copy